# Layout my tiles for me

Tags: code-golf, random, grid

I'm retiling my kitchen with different coloured tiles. In fact, it's going to have at least 2 colours - and 26 colours as a maximum.

But, I'm fussy. I want this wall to look random, but sometimes [random isn't random enough](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/23194/why-isnt-itunes-shuffle-random).

So, when I lay out my tiles, I don't want to have any the same colour next to each other in the 4 Cartesian directions. Diagonally adjacent is (of course) fine.

Acceptable:

```
┌───┐
│ A │
└───┘
```

```
┌───┬───┬───┐
│ A │ B │ A │
├───┼───┼───┤
│ B │ A │ B │
└───┴───┴───┘
```

```
┌───┬───┬───┐
│ A │ B │ C │
├───┼───┼───┤
│ C │ A │ B │
└───┴───┴───┘
```

Unacceptable:

```
┌───┬───┬───┐
│ A │ B │ A │
├───┼───┼───┤
│ A │ A │ B │
└───┴───┴───┘
```

```
┌───┬───┬───┐
│ A │ C │ C │
├───┼───┼───┤
│ C │ A │ B │
└───┴───┴───┘
```

Given input in the form `A B N` where `A` is the width, `B` is the height and `N` is the number of colours - an integer from 2 to 26 - you need to output a grid like so:

Input:

```
5 6 4
```

Example output:

```
A B C D A
B A D A C
A D C D A
B C B A B
D A D C A
B C A D C
```

The input will be given as a) 3 arguments to a function or b) as 3 separate input statements or b) as `A B N`. Input will always be valid.

All colours have to be used and all valid tilings have to have a non-zero probability of being generated.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so the shortest code wins.

Comment: ... come on, you're familiar with the SE network; you should know better than to delete and repost questions.

Comment: You [deleted and then reposted](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/63942/3808) this question (and you should know full well that's highly frowned upon on SE...).

Comment: There were no answers on the original question. If you want to prevent answers while you're working on a question, use [the Sandbox](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/2140/3808).

Comment: You know you can undelete questions, right? (It's also recommended that you use the Sandbox anyway, even if you *think* there are no issues with your question, because there could still be (this question being a case in point).)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31602/discussion-between-tim-and-doorknob).

Comment: @Tim You can undelete and then edit quickly. Just paste this challenge over the old one.

Comment: @Calvin'sHobbies should I do that now it's been reposted?

Comment: Does each row have to be printed space-separated?

Comment: @Sp3000 yes it does.

Comment: What's the minimum for the width/height? Are they at least 2?

Comment: @RetoKoradi one of them is at least two, and the min is 1.

Comment: Should the output be formatted exactly as in the example, i.e., using the first **N** uppercase letters, with spaces in rows and newlines between columns?

Comment: @Dennis Space and newlines yes. No, the arrangment should not be fixed with `A B C D ... Z`.

Answer (score 1):

### Python 2, <s>151</s> 149 bytes

```py
from random import*
W,H,N=input()
L='x'*W
exec"M='';exec'M+=sample(set(map(chr,range(65,65+N)))-{L[len(M)],M[-1:]},1)[0];'*W;L=M;print' '.join(L);"*H
```

Takes input comma-separated via STDIN, e.g. `10, 10, 2`.

Answer (score 1):

## CJam, <s>53</s> <s>52</s> 51 bytes

```
q~:L,'Af+a*a*{_::mR_:|,L<\_z:O|N*2ew::=|:|}g;OSf*N*
```

This will take a *long* time if **AB** is too large or **N** is too small.

Try it online in the [CJam interpreter](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=q~%3AL%2C'Af%2Ba*a*%7B_%3A%3AmR_%3A%7C%2CL%3C%5C_z%3AO%7CN*2ew%3A%3A%3D%7C%3A%7C%7Dg%3BOSf*N*&input=3%204%205).

Comment: I wrote a solution earlier but haven't posted it, see if there's anything you can use: `q~:K;\,a*{{;Kmr}f%{_2few:::=s\z}2*@@|'0-}g'Aff+N*`

Answer (score 0):

## Python2, 177 bytes

```python
from random import *
W,H,N=input()
A,l={chr(c)for c in range(65,65+N)},[" "*W]
for h in range(H):
 s=""
 for c in l[h]:s+=sample(A-{s[-1:],c},1)[0]
 l+=[s]
print"\n".join(l[1:])
```